# XPath for all element text that does not contain certain values

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have the following HTML structure which contain few email list, and I want grab email which email business, and not yahoo, gmail, hotmail, etc

```
<a href="#1">some@yahoo.com</a>
<a href="#2">s0m3@ymail.com</a>
<a href="#5">mail@yourbusiness.com</a>
<a href="#3">you@gmail.com</a>
<a href="#6">this@mybusinessmail.co.uk</a>
<a href="#4">me@hotmail.com</a>
```

So what I want is

```
mail@yourbusiness.com
this@mybusinessmail.co.uk
```

My idea is

```
get A tag which NOT contain ymail AND NOT contain yahoo AND NOT contain gmail, AND NOT contain hotmail
```

But how can I write XPath syntax according to above idea ?

Answer (score 3):

Your idea translates directly into XPath as follows:

```
//a[not(contains(., 'ymail')) and not(contains(., 'yahoo')) and not(contains(., 'gmail')) and not(contains(., 'hotmail'))]/text()
```

For your example (with a single root element added),

```
<html>
 <a href="#1">some@yahoo.com</a>
 <a href="#2">s0m3@ymail.com</a>
 <a href="#5">mail@yourbusiness.com</a>
 <a href="#3">you@gmail.com</a>
 <a href="#6">this@mybusinessmail.co.uk</a>
 <a href="#4">me@hotmail.com</a>
</html>
```

it selects

```
mail@yourbusiness.com
this@mybusinessmail.co.uk
```

as requested.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `substring-after` and `substring-before` to get the part after the ***@*** and before the first ***.*** combined with `not` and `contains`

So `substring-before(substring-after(text(),"@"),'.')` would get the first part of the domain and `//a[not(contains("ymail yahoo gmail hotmail", ...))]` would exclude the ones you want.

Altogether

```
//a[not(contains("ymail yahoo gmail hotmail", substring-before(substring-after(text(),"@"),'.')))]
```

Comment: Nice!   I'll leave my literal encoding up but I like this answer better.  Inverting the arguments of `contains()` in this manner is very clever.